# Why time difference formula field showing 1 minute less or more in time difference?

Tags: formula, formula-field, datetime

I am calculating formula to get difference between to date/time fields. But in minutes section it always shows 1 minute less or sometimes 1 min extra.

Example if Start Time- 08.06.2018 09:28 End Time- 08.06.2018 10:38 then difference coming as 0 Days 1 Hours 9 Mins Whereas it should be 10 Min.

I am simply lost from many days. This works fine with my developer org but not in the sandbox. Can anyone please help?

Formula :

```
TEXT(ROUND(MOD((ClosedTimestamp__c - OpenedTimestamp__c)*1440,60),0))
```

[image: Output in UI]

In DE org:
[image]

Answer (score 4):

`DateTime` datatype stores the data upto mili seconds.

From the datetime, you are displaying the Open Time and closed time at minute level and omitting the seconds.

Because of that you are getting erratic results.

To get more precise results calculate elapsed time up to seconds.

By the way, this calculation results should be same in DE or sandboxes.

You can refer similar calculation here, [Case duration of ageing](http://santanuboral.blogspot.com/2017/01/case-duration-of-ageing.html)

**Update based on comments**

To get the calculation perfectly at minute level, separately store the data up to minute level the way `Date1` and `Date2` are showing and then formula should calculate the difference from those fields.

Comment: Thanks Santanu! Yes this is what I thought first but in DE org it always come correct but in sandbox it is always 1 min less or more. Added one more snap from DE org. Is there anyway to make it accurate?

Comment: Is that my answer serves your purpose?